# How do I enable the bcdiv function in PHP 7.0?

Tags: php, php7

The PHP function [`bcdiv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php) is not available by default. How do I enable that in PHP configuration?

Answer (score 21):

1. Install module bcmath

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php-bcmath
   ```

*(note: on ubuntu 16.04^ with PHP 7.0^ use php7.0-bcmath package instead)*

2. Restart apache service eventually

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: The answer should note that this wont work on php 7.0. At least on my machine it didnt work. Next asnwer - worked.

Answer (score 11):

Install module bcmath in PHP 7.0, you should try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath
```

And restart php engine or apache

Comment: This answer should note that [`php7.0-bcmath` is available in 16.04 and newer releases](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php7.0-bcmath&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Docker, then you can install it using `docker-php-ext-install`:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```